# What is the difference between Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-server-2012

What is the difference between Windows 8 (non-RT edition) and Windows Server 2012 (also codenamed Windows Server 8)? From a UI perspective they look the same

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: @CalebJares I can see how it's not asking for specific expertice, etc., but what's missing is the real reason for even asking this question. What problem is the OP facing, why would they want to know, etc.

Comment: My reason for asking is that the Dreamspark program offers Windows server 2012 but not Windows 8. I would like to upgrade to the new Metro UI and to experience the performance benefits, however I want to know the differences between the two.

Comment: Well my reasoning would be 'can a consumer use Windows Server 2012'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 comes in [four editions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart). Windows Server 2012 also comes in [four editions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012#Editions). Windows Server 2012:

1. Introduces [ReFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/building-the-next-generation-file-system-for-windows-refs), a new file system building on NTFS
2. Has support for [IIS 8.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)
3. Supports 640 logical processors, 4TB of RAM, and 64 Failover cluster nodes (much more than Windows 8)

Comment: windows 8 pro has IIS 8.0 optional

Comment: Functionality-wise, could I use Windows Server 2012 instead of Windows 8 and get the same result? I'm a student and Dreamspark offers Server for free, but not 8 :(

Comment: @liamzebedee - I suppose you could but you might not be able to run your favorite software.  Windows Server 2012 is NOT a desktop operating system. Infact you have to enable a desktop, and other features, My suggestion is just buy `Windows 8 Pro` its less then $40 if you already have Windows 7